# Connecting to bitcoin server from website

Tags: php, api, rpc, bitcoin

I'm trying to set up a faucet but am having trouble on the website side connecting to the wallet. I have the daemon running on my local machine and the site running on my hosting server. I have configured the bitcoin.conf file on my local machine with the following:

```
listen=1
server=1
daemon=1
rpcssl=1
rpcsslciphers=DEFAULT:@STRENGTH
rpcsslcertificatechainfile=server.cert
rpcsslprivatekeyfile=server.pem
rpcuser=[username]
rpcpassword=[password]
rpcport=[port]

rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcallowip=*hosting server IP*
```

I have forwarded the port on my router to the computer hosting the bitcoin server and use bitcoin-qt.exe -server to start bitcoin on local machine.

When I try to cash out on website, I get an error: An error has occurred - Unable to connect to RPCUSER:RPCPASSWORD/<@IP:PORT/

What else is missing?

Answer (score -1):

You should use [json rpc client](http://json-rpc.org/wiki/specification) to connect, see also [api reference](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29)

Comment: You're not addressing Rodney's question directly. such kinda advises should go as a comment